# <col> element border thru CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I am using  to apply borders to specific columns only, it is not working at all to me..

other properites are working like background-color..

**Is browsers doesn't support column level border on tables?**

here my code

```
<style type="text/css">
.check_border {
     border-right: 1px solid black;
     background-color: #0000ff;
}
 </style>

<table cellspacing='0'>
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col class="check_border"/>
<col class="check_border"/>
<col class="check_border"/>
<col/>
</colgroup>

<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>Salmon</td>
<td>Shrimps</td>
<td>Oysters</td>
<td>Rice</td>
<td>Wheat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>United Kingdom</td>
<td>2050</td>
<td>1545</td>
<td>1156</td>
<td>5007</td>
<td>12254</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>United States</td>
<td>1358</td>
<td>1884</td>
<td>784</td>
<td>10597</td>
<td>24554</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Australia</td>
<td>985</td>
<td>65</td>
<td>518</td>
<td>2548</td>
<td>10548</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: works for chrome/FF http://jsfiddle.net/rt2800/9tE7j/

Comment: hmm i am testing in IE8 and FF not working... my target browser is IE only

Comment: how come the given coding is working in the jsfiddle site not working we need any <doc> tag?

Comment: What do you mean, `<doc>` tag?

Comment: Works just fine here on chrome :P
http://jsfiddle.net/n6sKn/

Comment: Also tested on IE8 and FF3.6 and it works

Comment: Thanks Mackelito, it also works for me
all we need is "border-collapse: collapse" this preoperty on the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PPK has a good article about it all. The summary of it is that styling a `col` is somewhat variable in browser support and very troublesome in application.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html

Comment: Thanks chris its worked for me after adding the style "border-collapse: collapse;" on table